# VSCODE run gdb on remote server through proxy

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, ssh2

I'm trying to use native debug (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=webfreak.debug) extention in vscode to launch gdb on a remote server through ssh.
It's working when I'm connecting directly to remote sever :

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "type": "gdb",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Launch Program (SSH)",
        "target": "./appli",
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolderBasename}",
        "arguments": "",
        "ssh": {
            "host": "xxx.xx.xxx.xxx",
            "cwd": "/home/username/project",
            "keyfile": "/home/username/.ssh/id_rsa",
            "user": "username"
        },
        "valuesFormatting": "parseText"
    }
]
```

}

Is there any way to launch gdb on remote server through proxy ?
Let https://www.npmjs.com/package/ssh2  command for example use my .ssh/config file

I want to launch gdb on remote server yyy.yy.yyy.yyy through a proxy xxx.xx.xxx.xxx

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure that I understand. Do you have already working ProxyCommand (check [this](https://superuser.com/questions/174160/scp-over-a-proxy-with-one-command-from-local-machine))? I would try to contact the author of this extension https://github.com/WebFreak001/code-debug/issues . EDIT: actually there is an issue opened for [this](https://github.com/WebFreak001/code-debug/issues/192) -- it's not supported

Answer (score 0):

It's working ! I changed the code of the webfreak.debug to handle ssh proxyCommand, using ssh2-promise : https://www.npmjs.com/package/ssh2-promise instead of ssh2